# MicroStrategy Web - Forgot Password function in Login Page

Tags: forgot-password, microstrategy, login-page

Currently, we are using MicroStrategy Version 11.3. The current Web Library gives us the Login page with username and password field.

But, in the case of a user forgot their password, there must be a way to reset the password means to "Forgot Password" in the same form.

If the user forgot their password, they can click on ‘forgot password’ to reset their password.

Do Microstrategy have built-in library for the function? Or we need external plugins to do so?

Below is mockup for the login page.

[image: login page requirement]